# elasticsearch BitSet Filter or something else?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a document of type "person" with two fields "city" and "gender" e.g.

```
person : {
  "name" : "x",
  "city" : "stockholm",
  "gender" : "m"
}
```

Example Data:

```
person: {name: "x", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "y", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "z", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "zz", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "f"}
person: {name: "xy", "city" : "uppsala", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "xz", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "yy", "city" : "uppsala", "gender" : "f"}
```

First Query: select 2 people **randomly** who live in stockholm

```
    size: 2,
    "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "city": {
            "value": "stockholm"
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {
            "seed": 314159265359
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Total hits of above query is 5 from which 2 results were selected randomly

```
possible result (As it can be random): 
person: {name: "y", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "zz", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "f"}
```

Second query: Now I want to select people who has gender "m" but have **not** been selected by first query.
something like

```
bool : must [{ 
  term: {
  "gender" : "m"
  }
}]
must_not : [{ /*NOT SELECTED BY FIRST QUERY i.e name = y, zz */}]

result:
person: {name: "x", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}        
person: {name: "z", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "xy", "city" : "uppsala", "gender" : "m"}
person: {name: "xz", "city" : "stockholm", "gender" : "m"}
```

Is this possible through any means in elasticsearch? Possibly through filters (Using BitSet for fast access to document ids) or dismax query?

Please note that the data size is in millions and if I extract data from first query that results in couple of millions it takes a lot of time which is not acceptable in our scenario. I only need counts and not actual data in both queries.

I dont mind doing it in one query as well if possible but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: do you need exact count or an approximate one suffices?

Comment: exact count is good but if it is not possible I will take approximation for now as long as it is close to exact count.

Comment: As it is random you have to manually input the must_not clause conditions. like "must_not":[{ "name":"y" },{ "name":"zz" } ]

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test case with your data.

If you query returns random data you are forced to make two queries 
The first one return n rows, you must take the n ids/attributes of the result and exclude them from the second one

The second query could be something like (I have written a filter to exclude person with name 'x' and 'zz'):

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "persons":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must_not":{
                  "term":{
                     "name":"x"
                  }
               },
               "must_not":{
                  "term":{
                     "name":"zz"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "gender":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"gender"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and the results grouped by gender is

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "persons": {
      "doc_count": 5,
      "gender": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "m",
            "doc_count": 4
          },
          {
            "key": "f",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second query returns the count by gender excluding the two results of the previous query.

For the firt query I think you need a different implementation of random. If you have million of rows and you first assign  each of them a random number and then sort the rows by that number it's unavoidable that it will take la lot of time. A more sensible solution would be to use a sequence field for each document, storing it and then generate two random number in the range[0..max of your sequence value]. with the two number you can query the data very quickly and the apply the second query. With this solution the response time would be much faster.

Comment: I understand your answer. That was my backup plan to do but its not a clean solution. The key point here is that in first query I want random 'n' results. Then in second query I want 'NOT INCLUDING' those 'n' results returned by first query. How can I do the intersection when I don't know which results were extracted exactly from 1st query . I might get an overlap or I might not get an overlap. I hope you understand my comment.

Comment: I do not understand what "random n" means. You filter by a field and you get a count for that field; where is the randomness? in your question you specify you need only the count not the whole data. What are you counting?

Comment: The results from the first query can be random and I only need a subset of that result. See the result of first query in first query. I need count of second query but according to my understanding it is not possible to do it in one single query that's why I wrote two queries. Get random data from first query, pass it in second query somehow negating the result of first query. I will update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes! That will work but if the result set from first query is in millions then it takes a lot of time...

Comment: I update the respone with a solution for the first query

Comment: Two random numbers cannot guarantee number of results. If I want 'n' number of results then this will not work. Moreover if I want to change the query order in some case (query some other field first) then it will also be a problem with pre-generated random numbers.

Comment: I wrote two random number because two was the number in the example. client side you can generate any random number you need, and issue a query to retrieve the relative documents. The result can be sorted both on elasticsearch and client side.